# Linq Index question

Tags: c#, linq

Can I write code like this with index

```
var someArray = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
var resultArray = someArray.Where((num, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

like

```
var resultArray = from num in someArray...
```

Comment: are you asking if what you have with the method syntax is possible with query syntax? if that's what you are asking, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are asking "can I use **query expression** syntax to get at the overload of `Where` that provides the item index, in the way that I can using **fluent method-chaining** syntax".

The answer is no.

As seen in the docs for [the no-index-parameter overload of `Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) :

> In query expression syntax, a `where` clause translates to an invocation of `Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. There is no equivalent for the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) extension method allowing you to use the index using LINQ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems to be to hack around the problem:

```
var count = 0;
var resultArray = from num in someArray
                  let index = count++
                  where index % 2 == 0
                  select num;
```

Probably better to use the other syntax.

Comment: Implement `TakeEveryOther()` to get `...from num in someArray.TakeEveryOther() select num`... but as Richard says, just use the other syntax. `TakeEveryOther` is only justified if you use it alot.